# register_taxonomy and variable rewrite slug

Tags: plugins, rewrite-rules

I use Wordpress last version. I have a plugin which uses custom slug for posts.

Here is the register code :

```
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_in_menu'      => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => it_get_option('destination_slug', 'destination' )),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'destination', array( 'tour' ), $args );
```

I want to know if it is possible to use custom rules for slug ? I need to add langage slug for french posts.

I want to do something like :

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => (substr($post->name, 0, 2) == 'fr' ? 'fr' : '') . it_get_option('destination_slug', 'destination' ))
```

Can I access post in register function ?

Comment: Posts are not available when you are registering the CPT. You'll need to use another method - an .htaccess rewriterule or something similar.

Comment: Consider using the [WP Rewrite API](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-rewrite-api-the-basics--wp-25474). This will let change your URLs without touching your .htaccess file.

Comment: Ok i will use the edit_term filter to add custom rule. It's really complicated...